# How to ensure a posix c socket is still valid

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix

I,m working on an embedded linux kernel 2.6 device and need to know if previously established socket is still valid or not,Also I can not do this with usual send function and check the returned value,because if I send to the invalid socket descriptor,my application will crash and linux will shut down my process.Is there any other function/suggestion for this ?

***EDIT:***
There are an installed app manager in device and when I try to send to socket descriptor which is not refer to the open socket,app manager will end my application,then if i close a socket connection and try to write to it,my application will be turned off by lower level app-manager.Also I'm using TCP sockets,WBr.

Comment: What do you mean for still valid? Also, what kind of socket are you referring to? Local, TCP or UDP? Please, clarify your question

Comment: Also, why would your app crash if sending on an invalid socket?

Comment: Your application will *not* crash, unless you write something to cause it to crash.

Comment: Please use new lines and proper formatting for your question. It's super hard to read when it looks like a wall of letters.

Comment: "If I close a socket and try to write to it" is completely different from "if the other end of the socket was closed". If you close *your end* of the socket then try to write to the (now invalid) file descriptor, that's your fault - it's a logic bug in your code. Don't do it.

Comment: Then,is there any way to check if socket is closed,without trying to send data to that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this question is either misstated or based on false premises. There is no sense of "invalidity" which a socket could come to have asynchronously by the action of another process/host. The closest thing is probably the other end of the socket being closed, which **does not invalidate** your socket, but it does cause subsequent writes to your socket to result in an `EPIPE` error and `SIGPIPE` signal if not blocked. `SIGPIPE` in turn terminates your process by default. If that's your problem, the easiest way to avoid it is to block `SIGPIPE` with `sigprocmask`/`pthread_sigmask`, or ignore it with `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)`.